# Has Hamas commented on the burning of the Israeli dead during Oct 7?

Tags: hamas

There are [numerous](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/2023/10/31/israel-attack-victims-forensic-identification/) reports of Israeli victims being burned (sometimes after being killed) on Oct 7. [E.g.](https://globalnews.ca/news/10025479/at-israel-kibbutz-hamas-killed-elders-in-street-in-act-of-humiliation/)

> As in other sites attacked by Hamas, the bodies were grouped together and set on fire. “They concentrated them, they killed them, and they burned them,” the colonel said.

Has Hamas commented at all on the practice of burning the bodies? Do they admit it? Do they give a reason for it?

Comment: were 'just' the dead they burned?

Comment: @Angriffsreiher: Well, burning people (by setting the houses on fire) inside the shelters Hamas men could not get into has an obvious reason. So yeah, burning people alive is more easily explained than burning the dead. (I suppose one could ask if they admit to setting houses on fire to get the people inside, too. Didn't want to make the Q too complicated.)

Comment: @Angriffsreiher: given that Hamas [has](http://edition.cnn.com/WORLD/9602/israel_explosion/02-25/pm/) a  long history of bombing busses and admitting to it, it seems a bit pointless to ask if they admit to setting houses on fire in order to kill their inhabitants.